# If $AD+BD=CD$, is $A+B=C$?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-rank

Assume non-square matrices $A, B, C \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$ and $D \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times k}$. If we are given $$AD + BD = CD\,,$$ can we say that $$A+B=C \,?$$

I am thinking that we cannot just cross matrix $D$ out like we would do with a scalar, nor multiply with $D^{-1}$ since it's non-square.

What about the other way around? My guess is yes because we just multiply both sides with $D$. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What if $D$ is the zero matrix?

Comment: Good point. In my case I know D is different than 0, but it is still unknown. There is also one more unknown matrix, let's say A. I was wondering if I can just simplify D and find out what A is. My feeling is that I "lose information" when everything gets multiplied with D.

Comment: You can't prove it with an example, but you can disprove this by constructing a counterexample.

Comment: $AD+BD=CD\Leftrightarrow (A+B-C)D=0\Leftrightarrow \operatorname{col}D\subseteq \ker(A+B-C)$ and that's all you can say about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is the same as asking if $$XA = YA \implies X=Y$$ is true and the answer is no. That would mean that map $X\mapsto XA$ which is linear, is injective  i.e. it kernel is trivial which is not necessary.
Say $A= \pmatrix{0\;0\\0\;1}$ then $X=\pmatrix{1\;0\\0\;0\\0\;0} $ in it's kernel so it is not injective.

Or more direct example:

> Say $$X=\pmatrix{1\;0\\0\;0\\0\;0}, Y=\pmatrix{0\;1\\0\;0\\0\;0},A=  \pmatrix{0\;1\\0\;1}$$
> then $$XA=  \pmatrix{0\;1\\0\;0\\0\;0}=YA$$

Comment: I was thinking of finding a counter-example when $n=m=k$. Very good answer !

Answer (score 1):

Clearly $AD+BD=(A+B)D$ so we can waive about the sum and consider
$$
AC =BC 
$$

As an example take $A,B$ to be row vectors ($1 \times m$) and C a column vector ($m \times 1$) .
Then $AC, BC$ represent the dot products of A with C and B with C.
From their equality, what you can tell is that they have the same projection on C, which means
that they differ by a vector normal to $C$.

For The general case you can tell that the matrices differ by a matrix which belong to the null-space of C.